# Syntax error in matlab with parentheses

Tags: matlab, syntax, plot, parentheses

```
xlabel('\theta (degrees)'), ylabel('\rho');
```

I keep getting the following error with this line.

```
Error: File: hough_transform_example.m Line: 8 Column: 43
Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.
```

I'm not quite sure why though I do have the correct number of brackets I believe. What else could be causing the error?

Comment: Are you sure its this line which is causing the error? It runs fine on my machine.

Comment: Perhaps that comma should be a semicolon?

Comment: No, it runs fine with comma.

Comment: I found the problem. This was line 8, but the problem was in the previous line. Originally I had this figure, imshow(imadjust(mat2gray(H)),[],'XData',theta,'YData',rho,...'InitialMagnification','fit'); I removed the 3 dots and the error went away

Comment: The line number in that error message is just where the parser noticed the error. The missing or extra parenthesis may be on a different line in the file, probably in a previous line. You need to examine the whole thing. Do Ctrl-A, Ctrl-I to auto-indent the file to reflect its actual syntax structure, and the place with the error will probably become apparent.

Comment: @AndrewJanke Oh my! Cntrl-I indents your code! I love you a lot. A lot.